# Sample eSim LPA in Android

Tags: android, telephony

I am trying to learn about e Sim implementation in Android. While going through the docs [here](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/esim-euicc-api) i tried to understand the EuiccManager so used the below code from the same docs:-

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        EuiccManager euiccManager = getApplication().getSystemService(EuiccManager.class);
        boolean isEnabled = euiccManager.isEnabled();
        if (!isEnabled) {     
            return;       //always isEnabled is false
        }
    }
```

I used Note 9 real device with Android 9(Pie) version for testing the code so we need to add any permission in Manifest file or am i missing something.

Comment: Note 9 doesn't support esim. That is why isEnable() returns false.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following snippet with `Context.EUICC_SERVICE` .

```
EuiccManager euiccManager = (EuiccManager)context.getSystemService(Context.EUICC_SERVICE);
```

`EuiccManager#isEnabled()` generally returns true if the `android.hardware.telephony.euicc` feature is defined and an LPA package is present.

https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/esim-overview

Comment: thanks i tried in Pixel 3 simulator the same code the result is not enabled so do we need real device that supports esim to test the code?

Comment: yeah, that's most likely the case. Try it with proper hardware.

Answer (score 0):

regarding the manifest file you might need to add these

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTIONS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem. When I tried on several devices, all of them were false. I wonder if it is the reason that the device does not support eSIM.
System permissions according to the document added all I need, also added a feature android. Hardware. A telephony. The euicc (using the PackageManager hasSystemFeature check, the result is true).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).